# Jquery Ajax returns NULL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a little script to request json data from my database. Here is the Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var keyword = "1";
         var baseurl1 = "json_data2.php?l=" + keyword;
        // Product Count 
        var json = (function() {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': baseurl1,
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function(data) {
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
        })();
        console.log(json);

    });
});
</script>
```

When my Feed looks like this

```
{"limit": [{"rows":"127"}]}
```

I get "Object {limit: Array[1]}" in the console. So it seems to word. I can also alert json.limit[0].rows and get 127 shown. So far so good.

When I try to get another feed of data which looks like this

```
{"posts": [{"productname":"Das kleine Ich bin ich","link":"if3OHlvncaIY7A7VGze7VSIeAAZAIZV83cvaG%2B5w3U48cuooMp9qZZJkdQzwyGEXgk8LCR9kD7nY6Y%2FSR0RnjRJo44jHguoaesLAa4mLhuKpuLsfty85ZaePH%2FHReJTc","imgurl":"img\/products\/mytoys\/das-kleine-ich-bin-ich.jpg","price":"13.90","oldprice":"","sale":""},]}
```

the console log shows up with "null". What could be the issue? I mean I change nothing on the code, just the Url. The datafeed is JSON and I also visited the datafeed in my browser, it's showing up correctly. Any pointers?

Comment: why do u name the ajax request json?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, I just pasted it into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.org/) and it came back with errors. You should format it properly so it passes as valid json.

Comment: There's an extra comma in your json that's failing. Probably a copy paste issue though i'd guess seeing how the slashes are escaped.

Comment: Why not ? I'm just testing around to get it working. Later I will minify everything...

Comment: Why are you using `async: false`?  This *will* lock up the browser until the request is done.

Comment: there shouldn';t be a comma after the last array

Comment: You are doing this all wrong, with synchronous calls and strange anonymous functions. There are hundreds of answers on here that shows how to return the deferred object and do this the proper way, asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

console.log logs null because when that line is executed, ajax execution hasn't finished yet, 
your console log, and whatever you want to do with data that is being returned by your ajax call MUST be inside the success callback

Comment: The request has finished by that point due to the fact that it has `async: false`, making it a `synchronous` request.